# How can I contour plot a custom function?

Tags: matlab, function, plot, contour

I have a custom function which returns either `0` or `1` depending on two given inputs:

```
function val = myFunction(val1, val2)

  % logic to determine if val=1 or val=0

end
```

How can I create a contour plot of the function over the `x,y` coordinates generated by the following meshgrid?

```
meshgrid(0:.5:3, 0:.5:3);
```

This plot will just simply display where the function is `0` or `1` on the contour map.

Comment: Note - you should probably use a better resolution than 0.5, unless the function is extremely slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your function `myFunction` is not designed to handle matrix inputs, then you can use the function [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to apply it to all the corresponding entries of `x` and `y`:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.5:3);      %# Create a mesh of x and y points
z = arrayfun(@myFunction,x,y);  %# Compute z (same size as x and y)
```

Then you could use the function [CONTOUR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) to generate a contour plot for the above data. Since your `z` data only has 2 different values, it would probably make sense for you to only plot one contour level (which would be at a value of 0.5, halfway between your two values). You might also want to instead use the function [CONTOURF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html), which produces color-filled contours that will clearly show where the ones and zeroes are:

```
contourf(x,y,z,1);  %# Plots 1 contour level, filling the area on either
                    %#   side with different color
```

**NOTE:** Since you are plotting data that only has ones and zeroes, plotting contours may not be the best way to visualize it. I would instead use something like the function [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html), like so:

```
imagesc(x(1,:),y(:,1),z);
```

Keep in mind the y-axis in this plot will be reversed relative to the plot generated by [CONTOURF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html).

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it:

```
function bincontour
    clear; clc;

    xrange = 0:.5:3;
    yrange = 1:.5:5;
    [xmesh, ymesh] = meshgrid(xrange, yrange);
    z = arrayfun(@myFunction, xmesh, ymesh);

    contourf(xrange, yrange, z, 5)
end

function val = myFunction(val1, val2)
    val = rand() > 0.5;
end
```